# Using Fault Injection on redhat 6.5

Tags: linux-kernel, redhat

I simulate the fault disk using Fauly Injection (https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/fault-injection/fault-injection.txt). 
But the /sys/kernel/debug/fail_make_request/ path don't exist.
So how can I enable or install it?

Comment: Try building your kernel with CONFIG_FAIL_MAKE_REQUEST.

Comment: Thank @Peter, Im new with linux. So I will search google continue for how to build kernel? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The fault injection is not enabled in the default kernels provided by RHEL, while its only available on the debug kernels. Its best to talk to the Linux vendor for getting the debug kernel or supporting it enabled in the standard kernel.